# Issue with WFFM Send Email Editor saying 'no editor'

Tags: wffm

I am getting "no editor" error message on the Send Email Editor dialog as shown below:

[image]

Any pointers on what could be missing? Any configuration file to check?

I am using Sitecore XP 7.0 running on Windows Server 2012R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the root cause and fix.

Sitecore hotfix Sitecore.Support.416400 introduces Issues with the Send Email action in the Web Forms For Marketers module. This is documented on KB link below
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/581527

There is a workaround provided by Sitecore (a manual fix is needed on RichText.js file)

Hope this helps.